# How to read xml file and copy the node in same file with editing

Tags: xml

I am new to Stack overflow and this is my first question. 
[please correct if I am wrong anywhere]

Now what I have to do is:

- Read the xml file say(abc.xml) which contains almost 1000 tag called `<build>`. In this  I want to copy the latest tag say 1000 and edit it and paste 1001 `<build>` tag.
- In this tag, there is one attribute called `<version>` which I have to update every time I create build and then copy the same new build tag in same file i.e. appending `<build>` tag at last of `abc.xml` file.

So in short, I have to copy last record which is 1000 number `<build>` tag and make edition in `<tag>` attribute with latest version and paste it in same file marking 1001 `<build>` tag.

```
<root>
  <build number="1000">
    <tag verison="xx.yy" />
  </build>
  <!-- new tag -->
  <build number="1001">
    <tag version="xx.zz" />
  </build>
</root>
```

This is my task which I have to perform manually during creating the build. So please let me know how I can achieve it and then can think of automating it in future.

Comment: Thanks @Tomalak I will take care in future.

Comment: What tools do you have at your disposal to do this?

Comment: I Don't have any tool for same. please guide me over the same.

Comment: Well you must have some programming language that you know or are willing to use.

Comment: @tomalak I am writing my build script in Nant and wondering whether I can do the same with nant or any other language. So please suggest as this is my first time to read xml file via any language.

Comment: I think you can use the [NAnt `<style>` task](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.85/help/tasks/style.html) for that, in which case your XML can be processed with the XSLT language. Please provide a concrete example of your input and the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

As you've not tagged a particular language, I'll chip in with a perlish solution. Perl has the excellent `XML::Twig` library available, which is quite good for this sort of thing.

In this code we set a handler for each `build` element, that figures out the highest build number, and stores a reference to that element. Once it's processed the whole XML, we know we've looked at the whole thing, and so we copy it, increment the number, and then paste it.

Like so:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my $last_build; 
my $build_number; 

sub update_build {
    my ( $twig, $build ) = @_;
    if ( not defined $build_number 
    or $build -> att('number') > $build_number ) {
      $last_build = $build;
      $build_number = $build -> att('number'); 
    }
}

my $twig = XML::Twig -> new ( pretty_print => 'indented',
                              twig_handlers => { 'build' => \&update_build }, ) -> parse ( \*DATA );

my $new_build = $last_build -> copy;
$new_build -> set_att('number', ++$build_number );
$new_build -> paste ( after => $last_build );
$twig -> print; 

__DATA__
<root>
  <build number="1000">
    <tag verison="xx.yy" />
  </build>
  <build number="1001">
    <tag version="xx.zz" />
  </build>
</root>
```

Which prints:

```
<root>
  <build number="1000">
    <tag verison="xx.yy"/>
  </build>
  <build number="1001">
    <tag version="xx.zz"/>
  </build>
  <build number="1002">
    <tag version="xx.zz"/>
  </build>
</root>
```

Comment: I want to do the same thing using java. Can anyone suggest how to do this?

Comment: I want to write a java program to do this. Is this possible?